# error when using accented words in glossary

Tags: glossaries, accents

I don't know if you can use accented words with the latex glossary package but I think you can because it would seems like a stupid limitation. I'm french and if I want to define an accented term such as "métadonnée" and use

`\newglossaryentry{métadonnée}
{
name={métadonnée},
description={text}
}`

I get a error message :

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError ...
#4 \errhelp \@err@ ...
l.57 \glossentry{m�tadonn�e}
```

I've done some research but nobody seems to use accented words in glossary!
It looks like a problem with encoding but I think that all my packages are good.
Here's what I use :

```
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
```

**EDIT** : here's a minimal example to reproduce what happens so you can see that it won't compile with pdflatex :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeglossaries 

\newglossaryentry{métadonnee}
{
name={métadonnee},
description={text}
}


\begin{document}
\printglossaries
\gls{métadonnee}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: please fix your example so that people can run it to reproduce the problem and test answers.

Comment: I am not sure but I don't think that `glossaries` allows accented characters as glossary key name. You should use `\newglossaryentry{metadonnee}` and `\gls{metadonnee}` respectively

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: Maybe using `xindy` in the place of `makeindex`?

Comment: @Bernard: The issue happens at LaTeX level. The first argument of `\newglossaryentry` is used to define some internal commands. So to handle this you have to add `\detokenize` to a lot of lines inside `glossaries.sty`. (And I don't know if this works ;-) ) A complete explanation is given by egreg: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175240/activating-characters-with-diacritics-accents

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: I see. Thanks for the link. A workaround seems to write `\newglossaryentry{metadonnee}%without accents
{
name={métadonnée}, %% printed word
description={text}
}`

Comment: @Bernard Thanks it works perfectly! I feel so dumb for not having tried it before...

Comment: Yet it would be better if this workaround were not needed…

Comment: @Bernard: Well,Marco is right.  I already proposed the gls - keyname without the accent. This is of course unfortunate in a language like French with its richness of accented words ;-) (But in German with üäö the problem would be the same)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to avoid the problem would be to use the accent commands:

```
\newglossaryentry{m\'{e}tadonnee}
{
name={métadonnee},
description={text}
}


\begin{document}
\printglossaries
\gls{m\'{e}tadonnee}
\end{document}
```